Accidentally Removed the Shader Editor: How to Restore It?
I was using the Shader Editor and slid the [+] mark to the left, but I made a mistake, and now the part circled in red is gone.

How can I get it back?


Oh you are talking about the Shader Editor. You can split screens to create new areas as demonstrated in the answer in this thread: and then in the upper left corner of each area, you can click the Editor Type button to pick Shader Editor.

I added more image.  The part circled in red is not display.  I tried sliding up the bottom of this page . But did not succeed.

In the red boxed area of your new screenshot can you see the clock icon in the upper left corner of it? That is the Editor Type button. You can click it and change the editor to Shader Editor

Click the Editor Type button as shown here https://imgur.com/a/eetaqEd then change the editor to Shader Editor

Sorry. I can't explain well.  I add more image. I want to revert [before]. Now, clock icon is not displayed. Before, I can slied the bottom of this page up  and click clock icon.

Thank you very much. This problem has been solved!

If you find it difficult to open a new screen by dragging from a corner then an alternative method is to right click on the border that separates 2 areas, a little Area Options pop_up menu will appear and from there you can choose to split the screen to create a new area.
In your particular case, slide your mouse down towards the bottom of the 3D viewport to where it meets the Status Bar. When the mouse cursor is hovering over this border between the two areas a little double ended arrow symbol will appear, right click on this and the Area Options menu will pop-up, choose the Horizontal Split option, drag your mouse upwards and then release. A new 3D Viewport will have been created. Now you can click on the Editor Type bUttom (top left hand corner) and change this to the Shader Editor.


I could solve this problem to follow your advice. Thank you very much!

Here's a more general way to reset the entire interface:

✲ CtrlS or menu File → Save...
✲ CtrlN or menu File → New
✲ CtrlO or menu File → Open...
N or click either the gear icon or the "<" symbol to bring up the side panel. Disable "Load UI".


Very useful when you download a file from Robin Betts and it has "headers" at the bottom of each area because he is so used to Blender 2.79...

Thanks you very much. I remember this command.

That last sentence...
